# Make search query with LIKE faster

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application where search query takes too much time. There are different search queries where `LIKE` (with `'%__%'`) operator is mostly used. I need some general guidelines (do's and don't s) for making a better and faster search query.

Comment: Check this question - http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/46917/6171

Comment: This could be your starting source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: This might be off-topic, but you could be interested by the [Full-Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Querying in SQL with a wildcard at the end is quite efficient, but there is definitely a performance issue with having a wildcard at the beginning.

One way around this is in SQL 2008 has support for [Full Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571(v=sql.105).aspx)

You'll have to change how your query works to utilize full text indexing, but it should dramatically improve your text querying performance.